# Best resolution for a 2x2m design in Photoshop ?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What PPI should a large format artwork for print be done at?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-ppi-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be-done-at)

I am required to create a 2x2m design that will be printed.
I'm using Adobe Photoshop CS5.

What is the best **width, height and resolution**?
I think it is odd to create a 2x2m document! Do you?

Comment: It should be 200cm x 200cm in Photoshop (1 cm = 0.01 m) and there's no reason why you shouldn't make it that big. 75 ppi is a good starting point depending on print process and viewing distance. That would be ~100 MB image, certainly not overly large with a modern computer.

Answer (score 3):

If the requirement is 2m x 2m, whether it's a client or your professor doing the asking, then you will produce a 2m x 2m poster and you will smile while you do it. ;-)

A 2m wide poster is intended for viewing at not less than 2m, probably more, so you will be more than adequate at 100 ppi (150 if there is a lot of fine detail). There's no particular reason to scale this. You can set up a 200 cm square document in Photoshop, and it will export to PDF.

[Disclaimer: If this is a class assignment, the *correct* answer is *the one your instructor is looking for*. This may or may not be the *practical* answer a working professional will give you, depending on the instructor. Not responsible for low grades as a result of presenting this answer as your own work.]