# Large size banner design issue..help needed immediately?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, ppi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What DPI should a large format artwork for print be done at?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-dpi-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be-done-at)

I want to design a large banner for computer shop and banner will be viewed from a far distance. I will be using photoshop CS4.Sizes to be designed are  11 ft by 5 ft  (132inch by 60 inch). My pc have Intel Core2duo processor with 2GB Ram.

What could be the ppi to use for this design without crashing down my pc. Will 72 ppi be okay?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should use Illustrator or Indesign for this instead.

Comment: e100 is correct, that question should answer it for you. Quick answer is that: 72dpi is likely fine for banners (note it's dpi not ppi--though they are related, ppi is really a measurement of computer screens)

Answer (score 1):

For artwork that will be printed, 300dpi is the minimum to ensure good quality when sent to print.

The best tool to use for such large images is a vector creation program like Adobe Illustrator or Corel Draw. You *can* do this in Photoshop but you will be limited to only that largest size. You can of course scale down, but if you wanted to re-create the design for a larger size, it won't be easy.

72dpi is used mainly for screen devices (like the internet).

Comment: There no need to use 300dpi for large format printing. It's overkill. No one is reading banner from 3ft away. Also, web graphics have no inherit dpi, as it's purely a screen graphic with absolute pixel dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

**Ask the printer what they want**. They may get you to do the design in 1/2 or 1/4 of the size in inches and keep the 300ppi, or the other way around. Either way, your file should be small enough to work with.