# What will be the appropriate resolution for designing panaflex of 5ft by 6ft

Tags: print-design, resolution

I am willing to know the appropriate resolution for making panaflex print of about 5ft by 6ft or higher as billboard print.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to our site! I've closed this as a duplicate, but this other question should be useful for you: [**What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/487/8708)

Comment: @JohnB Thanks for redirection to the same content.