# Canvas settings for larger designs in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

From the past few weeks, I have been learning basics about Photoshop because i have an assignment which i need to create in Photoshop.

I have to create a big banner of size 360 x 160 cm which will then be printed. 
Based on few other questions here in stack exchange, I have gathered that the resolution for printing should be 300 PPI, But now i want to know about the font sizes according to the size of the design i have mentioned.

Any answers regarding this matter would be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: Whatever looks appropriate. There's no way anyone can specifically tell you what size type to use.

Comment: Most importantly, this strongly depends on several aspects of the application, e.g., the expected viewing distance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 10ft minimum viewing distance for 360 x 160cm print, `the font size should be 1"`

http://www.thesignchef.com/sizing_guide.php

Use the sizing guide for different viewing distance and other parameters