# How do I edit my photo before printing a large banner?

Tags: print-design

I have made a banner in Illustrator and I've uploaded a jpeg photo as part of it. I'm worried that once it is printed at a much larger scale, I will lose all of the quality of the image. How do I edit the photo so it retains its quality?

Right now the entire banner is 1200 x 575 pts with 300 ppi. I have sharpened the image in Photoshop, but I'm wondering what else I need to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "uploaded a jpeg"?  Do you mean that you have placed a raster image in Illustrator?  You haven't given enough information to determine the image's quality/suitability for printing. What is the size of the image in pixels (not points)? And what size do you intend to print it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Answer (score 1):

One possible worrykiller:

Try to trace your JPG. Explore different Live Trace Options. You can possibly find settings that create a piece of vector art which is good enough and still not too complex. Too complex vector images can freeze your PC or the printing process.