# Creating a Large Image from a small one

Tags: images

I have an image that has been scanned from a 35mm slide. It is a tiff file and is  2.04 cm by 3.35cm with a resolution of 9600.  I need to create an image that will go on a wall and be 8 metres wide. Can I do this with this image and if so, how??

Comment: What software are you asking about? You can resize without resampling in Photoshop and get a large enough image.

Comment: @usr2564301 That is an answer that I'd upvote. Please avoid answering questions in the comments, those are temporary and made to be deleted later. Thanks.

Comment: @Vincent♦: I'd rather see quite a bit more information. I'm tempted to vote to close as "Unclear what the actual problem is."

Comment: @usr2564301 Then I'd advise you to either vote to close *or* leave an answer. Not both, don't leave the question in the middle :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "a resolution of 9600"? Do you mean DPI? If so than the pixel width of the file is (9600/2.54) x 3.35 = 12661px

Un-scaled, and printed at 8m wide, this equates to aprox 40DPI 
((12661/800) x 2.54)

Which would be perfectly acceptable as a print at this size.

Obviously you wont be printing this yourself at home, let your printer deal with the file & scaling etc.

Comment: I got a different number for the pixel size: 7710. If this is a value in dots *per inch*, then the pixel size cannot be greater than the value in DPI if the 'actual' size is *smaller* than an inch.

Comment: @usr2564301 - But the actual width is more than an inch (3.35cm)

Comment:  ... because OP lists the size as h x w. How odd. Unless it's a *portrait* slide?

Comment: I ASSUMED it was 3.35w x 2.04H because slides are landscape, usually.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that PPI would be the correct unit, not DPI. PPI (pixels per inch) tells us how many pixels there is going to be per inch on the paper. But DPI (dots per inch) is normally used to tell us about the resolution of the print itself. For example in offset printing, the seemingly round screen dots are in reality made of tiny pixels, called dots. DPI is the resolution of the pixels that the screen pattern is made of (on the RIP we have at my job it is 2400 PPI).

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop click *Image > Image Size*

This is what you will see

[image]

Make sure "Resample" is unchecked, and enter 800 as the width. Click OK.

[image]

Alternatively do nothing, and tell the person producing the print what size it should be. Technically, you don't need to do anything. Changing the dpi without resampling actually does nothing to the image file anyway, except change the print size, and print resolution.