# Someone wants me to make a 4x6 outdoor banner. How would I do this in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've read that Illustrator is probably the best way to go, but I don't have that. Any advice on producing this in photoshop?

Comment: If you've read that Illustrator is "the best way to go," have you considered free equivalents such as Inkscape, a popular vector editor with features similar to Photoshop?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be

Answer (score 1):

A six foot by four foot banner would be a rather large file. Are you printing this yourself or with a printer? If someone else is printing it, they might be about to scale up a smaller file, like a 3 foot by 2 foot file and scale it 200% to the final size.

The problem would be the resolution. Banners do not have to be as high dpi file, you can print a banner at 72dpi and it should be ok. But if you are going to scale it up from a smaller size, you're smaller file should be double the final dpi you want to print.

So you should build the smaller Photoshop file at 150 dpi if you want the final print to be 72 dpi.

Answer (score 0):

Through Illustrator you design by **vectors** so in order not to have a heavy file you'll be working on a 40x60cm page and than the printer will **enlarge your design without losing any information**. 
If you use photoshop you work on **pixels** which are not stretchable in a "safe" way...for this dimension you have no choice! :)

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/key-concepts/raster-vector.html