# Creating right canvas size for a project

Tags: adobe-photoshop, canvas

I have a project wherein I need to create a banner with a size of `205cm x 445cm`. When creating a canvas for this size do I need to convert it in inches first then set the resolution to `300 pixels/inch` or is it okay to just convert it directly to pixels?

**When converted to inches:**

```
455cm = 175.197 inches
205cm = 80.7087 inches
```

When I view the image size of this canvas I get `52559 pixels` width and `24213 pixels` height.

**When coverted directly to pixels**

```
205cm = 7748 pixels
445 = 16818 pixels
```

---

What canvas size do I follow when creating project like this?

Comment: Pixels don't have an actual size, their size is relative to the screen they are being viewed on.

Comment: This project will be printed once done. When i use inches and set the resolution to 300 my computer is having a hard time because the file is too big. Does it affect the quality of the banner when i use the converted pixels instead of the inches?

Comment: I think this question has been asked before - see [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merely set up your document with centimeters....

[image]

Note you can leave the `Resolution` field set to `Pixels/Inch` and input 300. Photoshop will do the calculation for you.

You certainly, don't need to convert *anything* to pixels.

Answer (score 0):

The artwork should be designed based off the resolution that it will be printed.

It comes down to what the resolution will be when it's printed  (this can include web "printing")

You should find out what resolution it will be printed at and design the artwork in that size.