# Designing backdrops at reduced file size

Tags: adobe-illustrator, dimensions

I'm designing some backdrops for a play using Illustrator, the printed dimensions are 18m x 11m.

What size should I make the document so that it looks clear but isn't a huge file size?

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 The OP is using Illustrator so resolution does not seem relevant here

Answer (score 2):

Illustrator is a vector editor, which means there is not limit to how much it can be scaled. Therefore, you can, in theory, design it at 1/1000000th of the ratio and then just export it at desired size.

That is a bit of an extreme example, but you can design it at a significantly smaller size and then export it to desired size (just make sure to get the Ratio properly 18 x 11).

I, personally, would design it at 1800 x 1100 pts (only because that is the size I'm used to on my computer)

---

May be helpful as well:

[What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/487/63979)

Comment: I would design in 1:10 due to the way illustrators internal precision works