# What will be the best pixel size?

Tags: image-quality, file-size, pixel

I often have trouble estimating best image pixel size to large centimeter size, without causing much loss of quality.

Today is no different. A client wants a chosen image from shutterstock on his wall. (as wallpaper). The wall is 6680x1200mm

I can see on shutterstock the pixel size from the image. But how can I estimate if the pixel size is high enough for the size of the wall, without buying the image? Can I calculate what the minimum pixel format should be? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: @Danielillo That's actually the one I meant to link to, thanks!

Comment: Hi Marlie, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Please have a look at the questions linked in the above comments, they are probably answering yours already. If not, feel free to [edit] your question by clicking the [edit] link. If you have any questions about this site or the Stack Exchange model, have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help]. Keep contributing and have fun around here!

Comment: I edited your question a little for legibility. We are a Q&A site, not a forum, and although we appreciate social niceties, those are usually reserved to comments (like this one) or [chat]. If I happened to erase some essential information, feel free to [edit] the question again.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:

**Pixels / mm**

In this case, if you have a normal photo, of 6000 px wide, which is fairly normal these days, from a 24Mpx camera, divided into your 6680 gives you a pixel size of a bit more of 1 mm. one pixel of one mm is pretty decent for a wall.

The long answer:

[What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

You can clearly see the pixel dimensions of the images in the images banks.