# Upsampling Image for poster print

Tags: gimp, resize

I'm looking to upscale the attached image so I can print it on a 90cm by 60cm canvas (36in x 24 in roughly). If I want the image to have 240 pixels per inch (is this too much?) Id have to get the image to 5669 by 8504 pixels in size. If I do this I get the error message that the file created would be too large (500Mb approximately). Can anyone help me get this picture to an acceptable resolution at the size I want to print it? [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Comment: You do understand that the printer does upsampling so unless you edit something in the process or use a better sampler then it wont affect your results much. YMMV

Comment: Ah I see I actually never thought of it that way, but thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the maximum file size in GIMP's preferences

Click *Edit > Preferences*, and under *System Resources* increase the "Maximum New Image Size". Note: this may make GIMP run slower, depending on your computer system, and how big the file is.

As for upsampling (resampling), it will degrade the quality, and I'm not sure if I would recommend that. It would really depend on how much you are resampling the image by, and what the original image size was. Small low resolution images will not scale up well. They will look blurry.  If the image is already quite high resolution (large in pixel dimensions), then you might get away with it. Perhaps try adding some sharpening too.

If the original image is the size of the sample you posted above, then it's already a 10.7 megapixel image. That's probably already good enough for a large size print, as long as it is being viewed at normal viewing distances, and not close up.

If you don't want to risk that, might I suggest 150ppi is probably good enough to rescale the image for a large print. Then add some unsharp masking. This is at 100% view (click on it to see it full size), you can see the rescaling I applied in the dialog.

[image]

See this related question here: [What resolution should a large format print for artwork be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Another question I have is if it would be sensible to replace the off white background with a white background so this off white colour wouldn't be printed? And if so how would I do that?

Comment: @EliasK. Whether you make the decision to remove the off-white background or not would be one of personal taste. It can easily be done by making a levels adjustment [like this perhaps](https://i.imgur.com/DOS9ACZ.png)

Comment: Thank you! I will try and do that to see if I like it more

Answer (score 0):

1. This is just a warning, you can override it.
2. At a normal viewing distance, you don't need an image to be more than 12Mpix (so 3000x4000 in your case)