# Why does Photoshop decrease resolution of image when saving as PDF

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf

I'm creating a PDF for print as a poster. I've tried several times saving my Photoshop PSD image as a PDF yet no matter what options I select (High Quality, X1A, etc. it always downsizes the resolution. I have turned off compression and everything else. I can't figure out why. I've pasted the file info from the "Get Info" option on Mac's Finder. The resolution is 1314x1746 px yet the image is 5475 x 7275px when I look at the PSD file in Photoshop.

[image: file info]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What are the compression settings for the PDF export?  Do you have downsampling enabled? Have you tried setting it to "Do not downsample"?

Comment: Hi Billy, thanks for answering. I have disabled downsampling and have set it to no compression.  Today when I tried saving I actually got an error that I didn't before: Could not save a copy as “Yoga Poses poster 24x36.pdf” because the document exceeds the 2.00G limit for saving Photoshop PDF files.

See Help topic “Saving and Exporting Images” for more information

Comment: It would seem your poster is way too big. Does it also have multiple layers? Perhaps [check the answers given here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be) about what resolution a large format print should be.  Also, why switch off compression?  It will help keep the file size down.