# Billboard Design

Tags: print-design, print-production

If I need to make a billboard design according to USA fie size. How can I make such bigsizes bilboard in my Adobe Illustrator? As while designing it starts hanging and takes a lot of time to save. How to hand over such a large file size to the Client in USA for getting it printed there? Currently I am assuming the standard size to be taken is Height - 14 feet and Width - 48 feet. Also how much standard font size etc. should I use while creating such big billboards? Thanks

Comment: Usually youd design them in scale, ask the printer that is going to handle the job. File size should not ever be an issue.

Comment: @joojaa: By design them in scale u mean outline all the artwork? What about the raster image resolution. There are hardly any such large resolution images available. Can we give the .ai designed file in a small size and the printer can resize it according to their needs?

Comment: I get the distinct feeling that you are one of the peopel who think print has to be 300 dpi, which is not a magic number. Large scale print is frequently in the 100's range. But yeah obviously also pixels would be in scale.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly u mean by large scae rint in 100's range. I am doing the billboard design for the first time. So wanted to know the details to worked upon and considered before creating a billboard file and design in .AI. I would really appreciate if u cud explain it me to in a lil more detail pls? What size of the file should I take, how much DPI? How to workout with a raster image because that will come blurred in a final large scale file?

Comment: Most artwork pixel dimensions max out at a3-a2 size, so number of pixels stays the same. So human sized posters in bus stops are usually 150 dpi and billboards are less. See your not looking at that image up close, yeah its blurry if you look at it the same way as you look at a newspaper, but nobody is going to look at the image at such distances.

Comment: I see... that's a good insight. So u mean I should take 100 dpi with any feet size in width or height. And images should be of how much pixels 72 or larger?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be) 300ppi is really only used when the artwork is at 50% scale or less. Typically I've created billboards are 25% size and 300ppi.