# how to make one image that is compatible with the international Paper Size (ISO) file for printing: 5"x7", A5, A4, A3, A2, A1, 50x70 cm

Tags: resize, image-editing

how to make one image that is compatible with the  international Paper Size (ISO) file for printing: 5"x7", A5, A4, A3, A2, A1, 50x70 cm

Comment: What do you mean by "compatible"?

Comment: We need some more information to be able to help you. Which application(s) are you using? What do you mean by "image"? Do you mean a photo, digital painting or perhaps a design with typography and multiple images? The formats you are mentioning are not exactly similar (but almost). I would normally make the image suitable for the largest size in Photoshop and then use InDesign or Illustrator to create a pdf for each size I need to print. An image can't really be said to have a size before it's placed in a layout program an given physical dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

The ISO paper sizes have a proportion of 1 to √2 (or 1:1.4142)

So, make one file of that proportion and voila!

Want some examples?

10,000px x 14,142px.

---

Or open your program and choose your paper size. For example A3.

---

If you have already a file of some other proportion, just crop the image.

---

Another point would be Resolution. There are many posts regarding resolution on the forum. You can search the tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up your initial document for A4 printing, at 300dpi (2480px x 3508px or 8.6 megapixels). Then you can print it any size you want as long as the aspect ratio is the same. Sheets that aren't the same aspect ratio will crop the image.

For larger prints, it should still look good at normal/comfortable viewing distances. It's a common error to assume that larger prints need higher resolution, when the opposite is generally true - see the related question here: [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be).

You would really only need higher resolution images if viewers are going to look at the image really close up (closer than would be comfortable for most people).  If you do want a higher resolution image then perhaps set up your document for an A3 print at 300dpi (3508px x 4960px, or 17.4 megapixels).

Be aware that images which contain rasterized text or graphics, when printed large, might not look so good.  If it's a poster which contains such elements it's probably better to add these with a vector image editor (or in Photoshop without rasterization of text layers/vector layers), and then output as a PDF, so that they remain sharp at any size.