# I was asked to design a 3 feet x 10 feet banner but I'm not sure what resolution and what not

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm making the design in photoshop. I was asked by my employer to design a 3ft x 10 ft banner for an event. It's my first time designing a banner. I was thinking if I could use 3 inches by 10 inches canvas to work on at a 768 resolution(ppi).

Is it still going to look alright after printing as the image is going to stretch 12 times the original working size?

Comment: im sorry. correction : 762 ppi

Answer (score 0):

I think [this previous Graphic Design StackExchange question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be) and its top answer have a lot of really good information you should peruse before proceeding, although I'm not sure it answers your question directly.

My answer would be: no, this won't look alright, you need to start with a higher ppi. A 3"×10" canvas at 762 dpi equates to 63.5 dpi at 120"×36". ~64 dpi will appear pixelated even standing 10 or up to 20 feet away from the display. In my experience, 150 dpi is a working minimum for large format graphics (except for desktop banners and boards where the audience may be viewing from less than 2-3 feet away, which really need a standard pixel density 300+ dpi). By this standard, your minimum pixel dimensions should be 18000*5400.

You also, ideally, want to find out what specs the print vendor requires for production-ready artwork. Some large format vendors have a minimum dpi for raster files, and some won't accept artwork scaled to anything other than the final print dimensions.