# What size does my Photoshop file need to be to be able to print on A4?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

I want to design my artwork in a size which can be fit on standard A4 paper, which means i want to print it on A4 size paper both side. I design my artwork in Adobe Photoshop. Can anybody please tell me for that what exact size I will have to work on, so that i can give it to the printing guys? I am so confused about which size i have to prepare so that i can print it on A4 size.

Comment: Hi yasar, welcome to GDSE! We try to be welcoming to all users and will gladly accept questions from people of all backgrounds. But please invest a bit of your time in punctuation and formatting. Also, we understand that the issue you are facing might be urgent for you, but please don't ask for ASAP help. Lastly, refrain from using all caps, since it's considered SHOUTING and thus impolite. I hope the answers you receive help you with your issue. Feel free to browse around the site, ask more (properly formatted) questions, upvote quality content and maybe leave answers of your own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Comment: Also ask your printing guys what resolution they want (roughly: resolution = pixels/inch; print size = paper size).

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop already has all the settings stored in its presets to create an A4 document for you automatically, that can then be printed.

Click *File > New*, and choose the "Print" presets from the bar along the top, and select the "A4" blank document preset.  The rest of the settings will be automatically applied to your document.  Then hit "Create".

Example of the New Document dialog in Photoshop CC.

[image]

If you have an older version of Photoshop, it too will also have an A4 300ppi preset available when you click *File > New*. I don't have a copy of an older version to show you a screenshot.

Comment: thank you so so so much billy..i really appreciate your help..thanks man