# Is the maximum Magicavoxel render resolution high enough for art prints?

Tags: print-design, png, magicavoxel, render-settings

I love Magicavoxel and would like to experiment with having third parties make high quality art prints for framing. My concern: is the 2048 1641 image size limit enough for any sizeable prints? If not, are there any other options (eg vectorization)?

Comment: Roughly a 6.5x5.5" Print at 300ppi. However, 300ppi may not be necessary. [See Here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Comment: What if I render close ups of each object in the scene separately such that each object is 2048 1641? Would that give me roughly double the size if I combine the images in photo shop after rendering?

Comment: Whatever the dimensions, divide the number of pixels by 300.. that gives you the measurement in inches at print resolution. But again, for large prints, you may not need 300ppi. You need to ask whoever you plan on printing the pieces.

Comment: It depends a little on *how* you use the program. I use it for fun to create sharp "pixelart" with no perspective, shadows or anti-aliasing. These can of course be nearest neighbor scaled with no loss. Your idea of rendering the image in sections is good, but if you use perspective it can be hard to set everything up so the pieces fit together.

Comment: And you do have another seriously effective option: MagicaVoxel exports out several 3D file formats nicely, and it brings its native colourfile too... so you can import into any **3D DCC** (**D**igital **C**ontent **C**reation) tool like **modo, Blender, Maya, 3ds, Houdini, C4D** and do the render there at whatever output resolution (AND anti-aliasing depth and depth of field and so on) you see fit.