# Warning Noob PS question - Photo collage

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, canvas

I can do most things in Photoshop and creating the collage is not a problem, however canvas size and resolution are a complete mystery to me.

I am wanting to create a picture collage to be used on wall paper. The area it will eventually cover is roughly 3m x 3m (that's meters for you US people ;))

I am told I need an eventual dpi of 300. Is there a standard workflow for this? Surely I don't create a 3mx 3m canvas?

help please?

Comment: Yes you do create a canvas with 35433 x 35433 pixels across. Although you may not be able todo this so you could try 150  dpi instead. Whicj works fine if you dont expect people to look at the image at same distance they read a book.

Comment: You may want to consider hiring a professional to help you. Thisway you wil have less suprises, because you will also most likely have color issues.

Comment: 300dpi is for small prints, like you would find in a magazine or brochure, but it's excessive for large format prints. Although this may seem unintuitive, typically the larger the print is, the more you can get away with a lower resolution because the natural viewing distances increases for large prints. See possible duplicate of [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Comment: Also note that Photoshop might not be the best software for creating your design, since you mention making a photo collage, it might be better to consider using some page layout software instead, or even Adobe Illustrator.  That way you won't have to worry about making such a huge PSD, if you want the photos to be high resolution.

Comment: Sorry (been sleeping (Southern Hemisphere); Yes I think Bill's comment regarding a different software solution makes sense. Additionally the wall paper will be viewed quite close as it is in a corridor of limited width, color wont be an issue as it will be black and white. Thanks for the throughts and I'll continue my research

Comment: I noticed that you are using metric. There is a dropdown in Photoshop's Image Size window that lets you choose between ppi (pixels/inch), and ppc (pixels/centimeter). 300ppi = 118ppc. This detail is easy to overlook. Just make sure you know which one you're using, or you may end up with gigantic files for no good reason (ie. 300ppc).

Comment: @13ruce dpi/ppi is commonly used even when everything else is metric. I'm from Europe.

Comment: Good to know. I've recently gotten a few images from Getty that opened in Photoshop as ppc instead of ppi, so it's probably good to check anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the vendor for more clear direction on how to set-up your file. Most printers will have a sheet that lists file requirements to help guide their clients.

I suspect that they'll tell you that your file only needs to be a few CM across, but still 300 DPI. This is a typical setup for large format prints like billboards and vehicle graphics.