# Indesign advice needed on print/document size

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have created a large panel for an exhibition (7metres x 3.5metres). I understood that its normal practice to create a document size at scale for convenience. So I created a document 1/10th thinking that this will be fine for final print as we are working with vectors and not rasterized images. Unfortunately, the printer is saying that the resolution is too low, as he is using the packaged .pdf which when zoomed in does look blurry and bad quality.

Can anyone, who is experienced in producing a large scale exhibition banner please advise. Is there any way to produce/export the .pdf at true size whilst keeping the document as scaled size. Your help and suggestions will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If your document is 100% vector and done properly, there should be no blurring regardless of actual size. Vector artwork does not blur or pixelate by itself. See this https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The vector output is fine, but there are a lot of images which are linked. Those are the ones that are looking blurry, each image is around 1.5mb. The printer is insisting on working with .pdf which is small hence they are saying it's pixellated.

Comment: Do you have exact specifications form the print provider? In my experience, most printers will have "submission guidelines" which detail any scale to work at what PPI raster images (at that scale) should be.

Comment: Didn't you just say you are "working with vectors and not rasterized images" ? Now your comment says "there are a lot of images which are linked". Well guess where the problem comes from. Yep, exactly: at 7 meters print, you DO NOT use 1.5mb raster images. You need much LARGER raster images. The printer is probably correct and the artwork is probably not good for print.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, we are working with Indesign which supports vector, however, yes embedded in the IND are sets of linked images (its for a property company who are showcasing their properties.

Even though the sources images are quite small 1.5mb I am still able to zoom in to a high degree and the quality is still OK within indesign. The problem is, the resulting final PDF where this images then start to look blurry.

Comment: @Lucian, we do not know what the images have. They could be just icons or PNG logos so we do not know if 1.5 Mb is a good or bad size at all. Mb is never a measurement of quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be assuming something. That the raster images you have as original look "decent" and when exported they look "blurry".

You are probably using the wrong PDF profile, probably using something meant to be used in a "Screen" mode. Probably 72 PPI when used at 1 10th scale it translates to 7.2 PPI.

---

You need to look at your export settings. Disable any "resampling" on the dialog box.

I do not ID have it right now, but I think it is on the **Compression** tab.

[image]

Assign **Do Not Downsample** on all image color modes. This way the exported PDF will use the original images' size as they are.

Also, use the ZIP compression algorithm, not the JPG one.

Comment: This has worked. The pdf file is much clearer than the previous one! Thank you for all your help!  I will send to the printer and see what they say. :)

Comment: Just take a look on the other settings you need, like color mode and embeding fonts.