# Need help figuring out how to blow up photo for extremely large mural

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-production, photography

I'm working on an exhibit design and I'm trying to work out how to blow up this photo to fit a very large wall.

The photograph is:
19.28 x 12.87 in, 22.3 MP, and 300dpi

The wall is:
13 ft by 31ft

Can anyone help me figure this out? I'm trying to look up how to do this and the only tutorials i'm finding are for small accent walls or prints. I have no idea how to even do the math for this. The photo needs to be pretty good quality because people are going to be walking right up to it, like seeing it within 3 feet of their face.

edit: I need to know how the math works for calulating this, in addition to the correct dpi from this viewing distance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Comment: Most likely no theory changes a thing. You just scale the image and thats it. Ots not line you can do much beyter in anycase