# Enlarging a Tiff File

Tags: resize, file-format, dimensions, tiff

I have no experience with Tiff files so I am hopeful you will forgive me.

I am interested in trying to enlarge a print to canvas. The current Tiff file is 8205 x 5426px (27.4" X 18.3" @ 300 dpi).

Is there enough data in this file to double its size, 54.8" x 36.6"?

If so, once the dimensions have been added, would I simply save it in Photoshop as a Tiff file?

I have access to a Canon Pro 6000s 60" printer. My experience has been limited to smaller images so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Answer (score 1):

Speaking empirically, as someone who frequently prints to canvas, those dimensions are good enough for your output size.

Upscaling will gain no real detail. Good upscaling algorithms will give an *appearance* of preserving detail, but in fact you really won't see much difference on a canvas print above about 150 dpi.

Your quoted size approximates to 120x90 cm. I often print to that kind of size from 6000x4000 images.

Comment: I am very grateful for your assistance. Thank you so much! God Bless you. Lorraine

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is enough data on that file and you do not need even to resample it.

An output of 150ppi is almost imperceptible to differentiate from 300ppi on an inkjet-based print.

As you have access to a printer you can run an experiment yourself. Print a small file, probably a cropped section of the file you need to print just changing the resolution to 150ppi. Remember, do not resample the file, just change the dimensions.

Comment: This is wonderful information. I truly appreciate this.  God Bless you! Lorraine