# What's the recommended font size for standees?

Tags: fonts, print-design, font-size, size

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before, but it's my first time on this site, and it's also my first time making a standee. To be specific, we've decided on a 2ft x 6ft standee, but I'm not so sure about what size font to use.

If it helps, I'm using Futura PT for the body text.

I've read somewhere that 108pt prints a letter approximately 1.5" tall, so I went with that for the body, but it took a lot of space and looks rather massive.

Though I'm mainly asking for the recommended size of body text, additional tips regarding large print designs would be really great.

Comment: I feel this question is subjective. If you could be a little more specific (like what should be font size for heading / contact details / sub texts etc.), it would be better. There's actually no rule how big the font should be on standee. Bigger and smaller, all sizes work depending on requirements.

Comment: I think this Q&A will answer most if not all of your questions regarding large print design: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/487/41100

Comment: Hi @Vikas, thanks for posting an answer. As I said, I need it for body text. I meant to say the general text that usually comes under the headings and contains more information like, say, product descriptions.

I was wondering if there's a recommended size to make sure your text is readable while still looking proportional, like how 10~14pt is recommended for standard size books and the like.

Comment: @SkullAsphodel sorry I missed that part. Have you checked answers on the link shared above?

Comment: Thank you for that @PieBie, I actually came across that post when I looked for recommended settings for large prints. My question still remains regarding font sizing though. Like I said above, just as 10~14pt is the recommended size for standard books, I was wondering what the numbers would be for large prints like standees.

Comment: @Vikas Yes I've seen that thread recently and didn't get the answer I wanted. Though all that talk about PPI/LPI/DPI was very enlightening. At this point, the last resort must be to simply ask the chosen professional printing studio.

Comment: Also since you mentioned contact details in your first comment, do you have an answer for that? @Vikas It so happens there's a contact details strip (address, mobile number, email, FB, IG, and QR codes for FB & IG) at the bottom of the standee. Right now there are five 2-inch circular placeholders for icons and 72pt text for the actual details, but it looks like there's a lot of awkward space.

Comment: @SkullAsphodel IMO contact details and icons at bottom aren't the primary text, yet important. Actually, contact details aren't meant to grad the attention of people, but of course they must be read once they go through main concept of standee. So it is usually written in small fonts here in India, but still very legible. Can't comment about the space problem without seeing.

Comment: That's a good point, thank you @Vikas! I believe it's about the same here in the Philippines.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a scaled down standee. It has the same proportions as your 6 ft tall one.

[image]

Sorry for low resolution (=screenshots). But this is only about sizes.

The red texts are big because they are expected to be seen well from as far away as possible. They cannot be bigger because the lines cannot be longer. Some white around them is a must and some space must be left also for other parts.

The black title must be visible well at certain distance. Otherwise nobody will pay attention when they walk nearby. You must know how far people bypass it, but are expected to see the title perfectly. Make a test with a scale model. Have it on your screen say 3 inches wide and 9 inches tall. The model scale is 9in/6ft = 9in/72in = 0.125 = 12.5%.

Make it in your drawing program 9 in tall and zoom the view so that it's 9 in tall also as physically measured on the screen. This way your font size in the program presents also the actual size on the screen.

Let's assume you need good readability distance R. You should watch the 9in tall scale model at distance 0.125 * R. Let for ex. the wanted R = 30 ft. Then your test watching distance should be 0.125 * 30 ft = 3.75 ft = 45 inches.

Let's assume you find that title font size P in the scaled model fulfills the requirement well. Then real font size F = P/0.125 is apparently as big at distance 30ft. In my scaled example the font size is 16pt. If that's good seen from 45 inches away you need F = 16pt/0.125 = 128pt.

If possible the size should be so big that the existence of readable text should be seen also if the sight is directed say 30 degrees off. Make of paper a 30 degrees wide angle to test it. A person may not turn his head if he doesn't see there can be something interesting. The big red shapes on the top help this.

**The general formula:**

The height of the real standee = H

The height of your scaled model on the screen AND in your drawing program = S

Required good readability distance of a text = R

The test reading distance of the scaled model = (S/H) * R

The found good scaled model font size in the program = P

The needed real font size for the same apparent text size F = (H/S) * P  or as well F = P/(S/H)

If the title catches someone's attention he probably walks closer to see the details. You must decide how close he really bothers to come. From that distance he decides if there's something actually interesting. This gives probably a smaller R to calculate the minimum font size for the body text.

Comment: Wow, thank you @user287001!!! This was really enlightening, I'm bookmarking it and trying it later. Hope I get it right!

Comment: Copy the formulas to somewhere.This answer probably will become invisible soon. Math formulas are not popular here because people who base their work on experience, artistic talent and during a long time refined skills see (maybe for a good reason) that the simplest level elementary engineering here without showing a slightest hint of artistic ability is nothing but a way to spit on their faces

Comment: I dont think thats true.