# PLEASE HELP making a file with the most insane dimensions I have ever seen

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, print-production, dimensions, dieline

I am trying to PhotoShop decals for a vending machine going into my works new office building but cant make any sense of this blueprint let alone measure its dimensions accurately into photoshop. If anyone could PLEASE help me get this into a template.psd so I can design it... I would be eternally grateful.

[image: here is a model 3589-19 vending machine decal guide... if you know how to tackle this in photoshop, please help.]

Comment: The measurements are from 0 up.... so start at the bottom (0).. the first item on the left starts at 10.333 inches from 0 (the bottom), then ends at 18.832 inches from 0 (the bottom).. meaning the actual item is 8.499 inches tall... etc. Same for the horizontal.. it starts on the left at 0 and measurements are from that starting point. I, personally, wouldn't use Photoshop for this. But that's me.

Comment: sorry I had an incorrect digit.... 10.343, 18.832 meaning the item is 8.489" tall. ----The measurements, from the bottom, for the small items on the right are all *on center* - meaning to the center of the shape. The Ø measurements are the circle diameters.

Comment: Bottom right says scale is 1:10 – so open file and increase size by 10x.

Answer (score 2):

1. Stop using the wrong tool. Use Illustrator first.
2. Ask for a PDF file of that blueprint. If it is drawn correctly that file IS your template. Just remove the lines you do not actually need.
3. Define a scale and draw internally a rectangle where you want your raster image, your Ps file.

You can make a clipping mask and put all the lines inside. Now Export this to a raster image with the right resolution.

a. A bitmap only the real size you actually need.

b. The additional reference lines to guide your additional decisions when working on Ps.

4. You can, if needed, place your finished artwork inside the Ai file again.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably what you have in that picture is a screenshot of a vector format file (EPS or PDF or AI), in which case great, you already have what you need.

Open it in Illustrator, clean up what you don't need, lock the layer, then create another layer and start drawing on top of the template.

When you're done, move the template layer (what you call the *blueprint*) on top of the layer stack.

Show this to the print shop in a PDF format, they'll tell you if anything else is needed and possibly arrange the final processing for you.

If you need to use Photoshop for some reason...

- design the artwork as a very large, very high-res rectangular box
- the overall box size seems to be at least 67 by 49 inches and see [this topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be) on how to set up for high-res work
- overlay the blueprint to make sure you place any text and information in the right places
- show this to the print shop and they'll tell you what the final steps should be, or they might do the final processing for you