# How do i sell multiple sizes of a digital art print?

Tags: print-design, digital-printing, multiple-sizes

I'm hoping to sell some digital art prints on Etsy but I'm very lost as to how I can provide various sizes for one aspect ratio. I'm aware this seems like a very dumb question to ask but I am really confused.

Let's say I'm selling an art print for ISO sizes (A1,A2, A3,A4,..etc). Would I only need to upload the largest size (so A1 in this case) and be done? Or do I need to provide the other sizes too? My logic is that if it's the same aspect ratio then when printing it, it will scale up/down automatically to the buyer's needs.  I sound very wrong and I would appreciate someone to help me on this matter.

Thank you!

Comment: You are right that if you have an A1 image in proper resolution, it can be scaled *down* to A2, A3, A4. Scaling *up* would decrease quality. But that's the technical part. How *Etsy* works and wants you to upload, I have no idea.

Comment: you should ask Etsy

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea what Etsy's requirements are, or even if they have any. Maybe check on their website.

Anyway, here's one possible solution to resizing:

1. Create your original art at A3 size, 300ppi
2. Change to 150ppi, resampling disabled. This will print at A1
3. Change to 212ppi, resampling disabled. This will print at A2
4. Change to 424ppi, resampling disabled. This will print at A4

Changing the PPI without resampling basically changes the print size without affecting image quality or the number of pixels (the true resolution of the image).

Example from Photoshop's Image Size dialog

[image]

Note: Generally, when printing at large format sizes A1, A2, etc, you don't really need to print at 300ppi because the larger the print, the larger the natural viewing distance. An A1 print at 150ppi will look just as good as an A3 print at 300ppi. For more info see: [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be).

There may be some exceptions to this where you might need higher resolution images, for example if the art is very detailed, or if you want people to be able to examine a large format print up close. In such cases you might want A1 at 300ppi as your base size, but that will increase the file sizes substantially, and especially if you have multiple layers.