# DPI for A0 size

Tags: print-design, print-production, dpi

When designing an A0 sized poster (1189mm x 841mm), what DPI should your images be?

Would they still need to be 300dpi? or could you get away with around 200–250ish seeing as people will be viewing it from further away?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Does this answer your question? [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Comment: Usually 120-150 is okay for posters this big. Even 200 is perfectly ok for a A4 size

Comment: @joojaa thanks, I prefer this over the linked answer... the latter was far too long-winded!

Comment: Sure, but  consider that if  you dont know why then you might be the guy who orders 100 000 copies at 180 dpi when it really really needs to be 340. So its important to know why you need a value not just rely on magic knowhow.