# Can not save as PDF from large artboards in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a 530 cm (=208 inches) document in illustrator and want to save it as PDF. Due to limitation of saving as PDF (maximum 200 inches=508 cm), is there any trick to do it for larger than 200 inches documents?
Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Comment: You could design at 1/2 scale, and tell your printer to enlarge it when you send them your PDF.

Comment: Yes, usually when the size is this big, you can safely scale down the artboard to 1/2, or even 1/4. Talk to the printer, THEY WILL 100% know what THEY usually expect to get, when an item is 200+ inches in size. You definitely don't need to have the artboard at 1:1.

Comment: Dear Lucian! What do you mean by 'scale down the artboard to 1/2'? How can I do it and if I do it, then the problem is solved?

Comment: MAKE THE DOCUMENT HALF IN SIZE = 208 INCHES / 2 = 104 INCHES AND ALSO TRY 52 INCHES, AND TALK TO YOUR PRINTER ABOUT THIS :) IT PROBABLY DOES NOT NEED TO BE 208 INCHES