# Large format export

Tags: print-design, transparency, resize, print-production, tiff

I am tasked with retouching a variety of decorations to be used across small and large format print (up to 2000H x 3000mm W).
What would be the best export, resolution and size settings to use? I am creating the assets from stock imagery so I am aware some limitations exist.
CMYK and RBG exports are required in TIF format.
Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Comment: And always, always, talk to the printer