# Increase image resolution without increasing the image dimension on export

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, images, workflow

I'm trying to increase the PPI of my logo using Adobe Illustrator, but when I export it the image dimensions that should be 131x31 increase to 268×64. How can I fix it?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to increase resolution with Illustrator? Illustrator is a resolution independent application and the only place it even mentions resolution is the Document Raster Effects Settings (DRES). And the DRES has absolutely nothing to do the placed or linked raster images.

Comment: on that export options that shows 72ppi and etc

Comment: Is the logo vector or simply a placed raster image? What are you using to check the resolution afterwards?

Comment: is not a  raster just a simple text logo without drawings, well to check is just open the image, the illustrator saves it much more bigger than i would :/

Comment: "open the image" with what????? Not all apps read ppi settings and only read dimensions. For some apps a higher ppi setting simply means the dimensions increase. Like a digital camera... more megapixels doesn't mean higher resolution image, it means a larger image.

Comment: hummm thank's man :) well srry i'm not opening, i mean, i'm get the info that says - Dimensions: xxx, Color space RGB and etc. so, how can i increase the image resolution on illustrator?

Comment: Open the image with Photoshop.. what does the resolution setting say there? Info windows don't read PPI.

Comment: nothing more just this, anyway thanks for the help man, but this problem as i saw is the same of this question: http://superuser.com/questions/86254/how-to-increase-the-quality-of-the-images-on-illustrator

Comment: so i think that is nothing that we can do to change this

Comment: Well, I'm not certain there's need of any change. You've not really described the entire workflow, why you need a high resolution image, whether you're using jpg, png, tiff, or some other format, and why you're exporting it from Illustrator rather than just using Photoshop. You've not described the problem (if there is a problem) well enough. As I've posted, just because you see larger dimensions rather than more ppi somewhere it does not means Ai us doing something wrong.

Comment: Welcome to GraphicDesign.SE.  As it stands, your question is unlikely to get a good answer because it doesn't have enough information.  What format are you trying to export to?  What have you tried?  What, specifically, is wrong with the results of your previous attempts?  Please edit your question to include more useful information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's good to remember that as far as Creative Suite vector applications are concerned, 1 pixel = 1/72nd of an inch (1 point). If your image is 500x50 points (or even 500x50 pixels!) wide in Illustrator, it will export at that pixel dimension *only* if you export at 72 ppi.

If you need a higher resolution version at the same printed output dimensions, then after you have exported the image, take it into Photoshop and change the dimensions to what you want using `Image > Image Size`. Be sure to *uncheck* "Resample Image" in the dialog.

You tagged this question `website-design`. If this is truly what you want to do with the image, you should not be concerned with ppi at all. It is a meaningless value when applied to a web image. See [this discussion](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6080/what-is-the-difference-between-dpi-dots-per-inch-and-ppi-pixels-per-inch) for details of the difference between ppi and dpi, and [this one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/803/photoshop-resolution-for-web-design) related to web images.