# What DPI/PPI should a 4 by 6 meter outdoor billboard be designed at?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, resolution, ppi

I'm creating a `4 x 6 meter` (`~13 x 20 feet`) outdoor billboard advertisement that includes an image and vector logo (rasterized) in Photoshop. I was working using a smaller size for design purposes, but now the client has approved a final design and wants to go to print. I need to know what DPI/PPI I should export it as.

Additionally, I was given advice by a friend to make it at 30 DPI and work in centimeters (so `400 x 600 cm`) then let the print house blow it up to `4 x 6 meters`, is this true?

Comment: Related information: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1454/inept-knowledge-about-dpi-and-ppi-please-help

Comment: i make billboards all the time using photoshop … and follow the 1to1 rule…one inch equals one foot…with a very high DPI… the last one i made was 10 x 20 foot billboard…..my photshop file is 10inx20 yusing 1200 dpi resolution…..sharpening the final prioduct willelimate any blur or pixelation found on detail pics….(the Indesign idea is a good one as well) …a Mac PC will help as well

Answer (score 8):

Well, where I come from 400x600cm *is* 4x6 meters. :-)

30 dpi for final output is more than enough for a billboard of that size. It's not unusual for final output to be 12-15 dpi in this context.

The usual professional billboard workflow in Photoshop is to build the image at a small scale with high ppi (e.g., 4x6cm @ 300 ppi), but in this case you can work full scale because you're not exceeding any of Photoshop dimension limits.

What you really *must* do, though, is to **contact the billboard company**. Either their website or their production department will give you their exact requirements for file size and format. They will have Photoshop and/or InDesign templates that not only give you the dimensions you need, but the correct color profile. Use the template.

Added note: I've moved my billboard workflow to InDesign these days, and send to the provider as PDF. If you have ID CS5 I highly recommend that, for speed of production, accuracy and vastly better typographic control.

Comment: Thankyou alan, yes I realized 4x6m is 400x600cm, I had a slight brain freeze for a moment there out of frustration hehe... Your feedback is helpful, will get in contact with the print house..

Comment: but does indesign allow for files to be created as large as 4x6m? I have ID CS5...

Comment: When I'm doing a "goalpost" (18 ft high by 48 ft wide with a "bleed" of 18 inches), the company's Photoshop template is 5292x2052 pixels, 17.64x6.84 inches @ 300ppi including bleed. That's 8.7 ppi at full size. The InDesign document is simpler. I did some very simple math and made it 72x27 inches, 1/8th scale. In both cases, the document uses the color profile of their Fuji vinyl printer. I keep image effective resolution over 75 ppi and we're good to go.