# What PPI and DPI is needed for a photographic backdrop printed at 6x4 foot?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, dpi, ppi, print-production

What PPI and DPI is needed for a photographic backdrop printed at 6x4 foot? I have a stock image which is 4000 px across and 300 dpi. Do I need to enlarge that with photoshop before sending to my backdrop printer?

Comment: When in doubt, always ask your printer.  It's hard for us to really give you a definitive answer, without knowing all the details of their printing process, but I think that the image is high enough resolution to work.  Make sure you send them an uncompressed .tif, for any raster images involved.

Answer (score 1):

I would use between 72-100 dpi if the image could handle it, although you could maybe drop it down a little further if necessary. .

The longer the distance you view something, the smaller the dpi, at longer distances a higher dpi is wasted. So general rules would be.

**Magazine** (close up) 300dpi
**Banner** (medium distance) 72 - 100dpi
**Billboard** (long distance) 30 dpi

My biggest piece of advice is **always best to ask your printer**, an experienced printer will always help you get the best possible results.

Check out [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/67249/58159) previous answers for a little more detail.

Comment: If the stock image on-hand is the only option, then the truth is, the OP should submit it as-is without modifying it (aside from the appropriate cropping), and then ask the banner-maker to print it at the specified size. There isn't any benefit to the OP resampling the image prior to that. As you say in the linked answer, the banner people are only going knock it back down to (*foo* ppi). The main concern is how is the banner going to re-photograph, and it sounds like you have experience with that.