# How to Compare a Dot (used in printing) with a Pixel (used in websites)?

Tags: website-design, print-design

I am a web developer but I am noob in designing. I have an html page of size 640 pixel * 800 pixel. I have converted this html page to pdf using `wkhtmltopdf`. But my boss is saying that we need to print this in 300 DPI. So make it so that it looks good. I am not understanding how to treat pixel with dots?

Comment: First of all, it's [PPI not DPI](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6080/) - unless your boss is [a professional printer asking you to do the raster image processing (RIP) on your side](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/1455/3327), which would be very unusual. Almost certainly, they're just asking you to include higher resolution images.

Comment: It's DPI. Dots per inch. @user568458

Comment: ... possible to show sample of that page? What is the page composed of?: text and svg (line) art? If that page contains your vanilla gif/jpg/png images optimized for web use you'll in a world of hurt trying to make them look remotely decent.

Comment: Here is some reference for [the difference between DPI and PPI](http://www.imagescience.com.au/kb/questions/31/The+difference+between+PPI+and+DPI):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ppi is how many pixels are squeezed into a real-world inch (pixels per inch). If you want to print something 6x8 inches at 300ppi, it needs to be 1800 x 2400 pixels (6 x 300 and 8 x 300).

Typically for screen we use 72 or 96 ppi, but it is irrelevant as screen will display 1 image pixel per screen pixel.

For print, you can make the print quality sharper by increasing the number of pixels in each inch, so 400ppi is sharper than 100ppi for example. In other words, it is about how big an area you want to disperse those pixels. 300ppi is industry standard for printed materials.

A 1800x2400px image is the same size regardless of whether it is set at 72ppi or 300ppi. The ppi just tells you how to display those same number of pixels (which only really matters for print, as onscreen, density is dictated by your monitor).

Comment: Is PPI and DPI are same?

Comment: No. See the link I posted in the question comments for a more detailed explanation of the differences