# Scanning 8.5 x 11 paper in PS results in huge image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, resolution, scanning

I have a paper form that I ultimately want to us as a background template in SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio for a report.  When I scan the form, it results in a 5088 x 6600 image - which is way too big.  When I try to re-size the image in PS 6 (I know, but it's all we have at my office) the text becomes unreadable.

So basically I want to scan a paper form that is 8.5x11 and have it appear the same aspect ratio on my screen and also have it print out in the same size.

Comment: What dpi or resolution is the scanner set to scan at?

Comment: Closely related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95/what-dpi-should-be-used-for-what-situations

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is change the resolution of the scan. In the scanner settings there is a setting for "dpi". Currently, from the pixel dimensions you give, it's set to 600 dpi which is way more than you need.

150 dpi is probably a decent compromise between screen size and printability.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to same size like your screen then scan in 72 DPI Resulation and if you want for printing purpose then 150 Dpi is best size..

Comment: 72ppi is much lower resolution than any screen you'll be using.

Comment: 72 PPI is just for view not for print..

Comment: Yes, but what is your screen's PPI?

Comment: my screen resulation is 72 dpi

Comment: One of mine is 63dpi, the other about 110ppi.