# DPI v Resolution

Tags: resolution, dpi

What is the metric of comparison for DPI and the resolution of an image? I'm rendering a PDF to multiple JPEGs with Automator, and I'm wondering what DPI would be best to use?

Comment: DPI is resolution. I'm not sure I understand the first part of your question.. As for what DPI to use, what are the JPGs being used for?

Comment: I guess I'm looking for some type of comparison between DPI and a pixel resolution number. If there even is any correlation, that is. For example, if I render the images at 300 DPI, am I going to get a specific resolution (e.g. 6,600x5,100), or is the resolution completely dependent on the original image?

Comment: Also, the images are being used in a video presentation. I have to recompile someone's slideshow to their audio recording. Video settings are 1080p30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the JPGs are being used as assets for a video then the resolution (PPI/DPI) is completely irrelevant. The only time the resolution matters is if you are printing the images. The "I" in DPI and PPI stands for "Inch" and your video knows nothing of inches.

The de-facto standard for screen images is 72 PPI so if you have to pick one go with that, but it doesn't really matter. The only thing that matters is pixels, find out the size you need *in pixels* and output your JPGs at that size.

Previous Q&A that may be useful:

- [What DPI should be used for what situations?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95/what-dpi-should-be-used-for-what-situations)