# Adobe Illustrator: how to save at 600 dpi for print

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resolution, dpi, image-format

I am learning AI now and one of the requirements for a project is it must be submitted as 600dpi in order to be printed. Can I accomplish this with Adobe Illustrator? If so how can it be saved as 600dpi in PDF format, as the only CMYK option I find in AI for print is 300 dpi?

Can I accomplish this with just AI or will I need to use Photoshop also?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are referring to Adobe Illustrator, we can assume you are working with (mostly?) vector artwork, in which case ignore any dpi information. Or better yet, use the default 300dpi you get when creating a new AI document. This 300dpi setting only applies to raster elements being used in your artwork (pictures vs. shapes).

Then, when you export from AI to PDF, there is a 'Compression' tab in the export panel where you can set a higher dpi count (600 if you want to), but this again only affects the photos you are using in your document.

Since you are just learning you might not be aware of all the differences between AI and PS, so in case you are just mixing photos together, then yeah do it in Photoshop at 600dpi if they told you so (after you read [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95)).

Comment: Implied but not explained exactly: Vector graphics are designed to print at the maximum resolution of the output device. They are mathematical representations of shapes and colors, and these instructions allow a laser printer, RIP, inkjet, film processor and any other device to re-create the shapes and colors at the maximum resolution the device can handle. Images (raster graphics) on the other hand, have specific pixels, the number of which determine the image's maximum resolution.